# Conditional execution of loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following plsql block

```
for holder in (
     select pm.product_holder
           , cast(
                collect(
                   product_table(pm.product_no,pm.product_catalogue)
                   order by pm.product_catalogue
                          , pm.product_no
                ) as t_prod_cat_no_table
             ) product_cats_nos 
        from product_master pm
       group by pm.product_holder
       order by pm.product_holder
   ) loop
      test_proc(         
        holder.product_holder,
        holder.product_cats_nos
      );
   end loop;
```

In the above sql, if any one of the column is null, I wouldn't like to execute loop, it should terminate execution.

Columns are `product_holder,product_cats_nos`

How could I achieve this?

Comment: "If any one of the columns is NULL" - define "any columns". Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis I have included columns in my question.

Comment: Avoid loop at the first instance. Row by row, aka, slow by slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this like that:

```
loop
  if holder.product_holder   is null or
     holder.product_cats_nos is null 
  then
    exit;
  end if; 

  test_proc(         
    holder.product_holder,
    holder.product_cats_nos
  );
end loop;
```

Exit will break the loop.
For more information look up the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/exit_statement.htm

Another approach would be to make your test_proc procedure null proof, but then again I don't really know what you want to do ;)

Comment: Test your input for null and handle it there. I do not know what the desired behavior would be if there is a null, but by moving the checks inside the procedure you won't have to break the loop. So you can iterate over all your elements.

Comment: Thanks for insight, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that PRODUCT_NO is a column on PRODUCT_MASTER, while PRODUCT_CAT_NOS is an object produced by the query. Given this, it seems that to test the NULL status of these two columns/objects you'd want to test the first in the WHERE clause, and the second in the HAVING clause:

```
for holder in (
     select pm.product_holder
           , cast(
                collect(
                   product_table(pm.product_no,pm.product_catalogue)
                   order by pm.product_catalogue
                          , pm.product_no
                ) as t_prod_cat_no_table
             ) product_cats_nos 
       from product_master pm
       WHERE pm.PRODUCT_HOLDER IS NOT NULL     -- Added
       group by pm.product_holder
       HAVING PRODUCT_CAT_NOS IS NOT NULL  -- Added
       order by pm.product_holder
   ) loop
      test_proc(         
        holder.product_holder,
        holder.product_cats_nos
      );
   end loop;
```

On the whole, however, I think it's clearer to use an IF statement inside the loop - but it's your choice as to which method you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

product_cats_nos can't be null (it can contain nulls or be empty, but that's a different concept: the collection is not null by the time it is initialized as the first step of collect aggregation function) and you can only have the last **one**(you're grouping by that field) occurrence of pm.product_holder (because nulls are last as default when you're using order by) to be null.
Given this you can simply modify the query adding a where clause on 
product_holder is not null.